# Astyanax: How to determine the type of a dynamic column for deserialization

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I have a column family with strings and a composite type for column names.

When I get a row back as a ColumnList of ByteBuffers, I need to know what the type of the column is in order to use the appropriate serializer. Is there a way to get the type or should I be doing this another way?

Code:

```
ColumnFamily<String, ByteBuffer> cfBytes =  ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily("mycolumnfamily",StringSerializer.get(), ByteBufferSerializer.get());

ColumnFamilyQuery<String, ByteBuffer> cfq = keyspace.prepareQuery(cfBytes);

RowQuery<String, ByteBuffer> rowQuery = cfq.getKey("foobar");

ColumnList<ByteBuffer> result = rowQuery.execute().getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic Composite Column, you can use just the **Composite** type or the **MockComposite** type, for example:

```
ColumnFamily<String, MockCompositeType> CF_COMPOSITE = 
    ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily("CompositeColumn", StringSerializer.get(),
        new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<MockCompositeType>(MockCompositeType.class));
```

You can found more **[HERE in this link](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/5c05d118e22eef541a7a201adf7c1c610da13f5b/src/test/java/com/netflix/astyanax/thrift/ThrifeKeyspaceImplTest.java)**.

Or, an alternative for writing pure Astyanax is the **[PlayORM](https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a single row you can tell the type of composite column:

```
// Query the composite columns
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
OperationResult<ColumnList<ColumnFamily>> result = null;
try {
    result = oKeyspace.getKeyspaceContext().
             getEntity().prepareQuery(compTestCF).getRow("12345").execute();
} catch (ConnectionException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Column<ColumnFamily> col : result.getResult()) {
    String colClass = ((Object) col.getName()).getClass().getName();
    if (colClass.equals(CompositeColumn.class.getName())) {
    System.out.println(col.getLongValue());
    }
}
```

The name of my composite column test class is CompositeColumn, as seen above.  The reason this works is because the OperationResult is a `ColumnList<ColumnFamily>` object.  Each `Column<ColumnFamily>` object contains the composite column object as the name, which allows us to find the CompositeColumn class name. We can do this because the result of a "getRow" or "getKey" call is a RowQuery object.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to do this when more than one row is returned.  In that case, there is never a `ColumnList<ColumnFamily>` object produced for each row, but instead `ColumnList<Object>` objects.  That's because the result of any slice or range queries is a RowSliceQuery object, which for some crazy reason doesn't give you the same functionalty.  The col.getName() call returns an empty string for composite columns.